# Check (without authenticating) if a URL points to Azure Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

My problem is as follows: I have a list of URLs. Some point to Azure Storage files, and some to a regular global domain. I would like to split the list into two parts - list of global URLs and list of Azure storage URLs. It has to be done without authenticating because at this point it's just a random URL - I dont know what storage account it lies in and what key to use.
It also has to be as efficient as possible. (The files are .png images if that matters)

As for now, I thought about checking "Exists()" on the whole list, does it sound to you like a legit solution? Will it even work? Maybe there's something more efficient?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One potential hack that you could actually try here is to make a [**`HEAD request`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) to the URL. What you would need to do is parse the response headers. Each request to Azure Blob Storage will have a response header named **`x-ms-request-id`** which contains a GUID.

You can use this GUID to differentiate between scenarios where URL points to blob storage and global domain .

- If it's a valid Blob URL you will get status code 200 .
- If not, you will get status code 404 back however you will receive x-ms-request-id response header back.

Comment: First of all thank for the answer! It's a bit problematic, because in this solution I count on the fact that only Azure Blob Storage will return this header with a GUID, and I guess it's not always the case.. My solution has to be 100% accurate

Comment: You are right! As i mentioned its a hack, I dont think there is anyother way